# Finding out the version of git on remote server

Tags: git

I am looking for the git command on my local machine which i can run to find out the version of git running on the remote server? 
If this is even possible.

Comment: Interesting question. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am curious if my provider delivers what he promised me :-)

Comment: You can, if you have a shell account, ssh in and check out what's running there. Is that possible? Otherwise, I can think of a heath robinson setup where you put something into a hook which prints out the version of git.

Comment: I thought more about a standard git command what asks the remote about their version. I think it needs todo this somehow to negotiate the protocol version for pull and clone.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Modern git servers (beginning in [git 1.7.12.1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff5effdf455bd6e694ff0bb3e0793515a2214adb)) will return their version information in the *capabilities* negotiation in the protocol.  While it's accurate that there's no git command that you can run locally, you can simply query the git server for the information and a recent version will provide the version number.

You can find this information using HTTPS or SSH.

#### HTTPS

You can use a web client to request:

```
<repository url>/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

And examine the first line for the `agent=` report.

For example, against CodePlex:

```
% curl https://git01.codeplex.com/gittf/info/refs\?service=git-upload-pack
000000bd43569b9f6f29136b6544809eacd2417a308f9341 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack
side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed
no-done agent=git/1.8.4.msysgit.0
```

Which indicates that CodePlex is using Git for Windows 1.8.4 (`git/1.8.4.msysgit.0`).

Or against GitHub:

```
% curl https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git/info/refs\?service=git-upload-pack
000000f83f8d005a82b39c504220d65b6a6aa696c3b1a9c4 HEAD\0multi_ack
thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag
multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master
agent=git/2:2.1.1~peff-bare-reflogs-fetch-616-gc016f98
... ref information removed ...
```

Indicating that GitHub is using a custom git version:  `git/2:2.1.1~peff-bare-reflogs-fetch-616-gc016f98`.

#### SSH

SSH remotes invoke the `git-upload-pack` process on the remote server to communicate. You can ssh into your remote and execute that process. Like in the HTTPS example, the first line will contain the capabilities. Unlike the HTTPS example, you're expected to perform an interactive negotiation for what you're trying to fetch, so you'll need to instruct the remote that you don't want to communicate.

As part of the git protocol, that means that you'll need to write the length of the command, followed by the command itself (in this case, `done`) and a newline. This is 9 bytes (four bytes for the length, four bytes for the command, and a byte for the newline). So the instruction that you'll be giving the remote is `0009done\n`.

```
echo '0009done' |  ssh <host> git-upload-pack <repository> | head -1
```

For example, to get this information for `ssh://git@github.com/libgit2/libgit2` aka `git@github.com:libgit2/libgit2`:

```
echo '0009done' |  ssh git@github.com git-upload-pack /libgit2/libgit2 | head -1
014c13502d9e7f6c51a5f93ea39e14db707d382dc996 HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed allow-tip-sha1-in-want allow-reachable-sha1-in-want symref=HEAD:refs/heads/main filter object-format=sha1 agent=git/github-g54d96f1f66a0
```

Indicating that the current version of `git` serving my `github.com` request is `git/github-g54d96f1f66a0`, indicating that it's a development build from commit `54d96f1f66a0`, which suggests that they're testing a change in production.

Comment: Not as easy as i thought but still a valid solution. Would be nice if there would be git command to get infos about the remote backend though.

Comment: This endpoint, `/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` seems out-of-date.

Comment: @CivFan no, `/info/refs` is still the state of the art

Comment: How would one do this with authentication (using the ssh remote instead of the https one)?

Comment: also interested in a ssh variant

Comment: JellicleCat and @Alex - I added information about SSH.

Answer (score 7):

In similar way to what was suggested by [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741657/1307867), you can also use [environment debugging variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging):

```
GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git |& grep agent
12:31:40.317199 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< f92d495d44bff2bdb6fd99524a93986ea268c9e8 HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/github-g956b612bf136
```

And again, it looks like GitHub is using custom build of Git: `agent=git/github-g956b612bf136`.