# The tree contains an entry with an invalid path of '.git'

Tags: git

I am currently in the process of transferring projects from Team Foundation Version Control to `Git`. I have successfully done this twice using `git-tf` to download the code into a local git repository and then push that repository to a new remote repository.

On my third project, I am getting the following **error** when I attempt to push:

> error: unpack failed: error The tree object
>   e934502276892b903347a524cb066a14a19d8ac0 was rejected: The tree
>   contains an entry with an invalid relative path of '.git'.

I can not figure out what this might be as it fails when I push to `TFS` or `GitHub`. I would be so grateful if someone has an idea of how to remedy.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of git runs on the remote? This will help you find that out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738572/finding-out-the-version-of-git-on-remote-server

Answer (score 5):

For some good security reasons, Git refuses to store any files within any directory named `.git`.  (If Git *did* allow `.git` files, a file named `.git/hooks/commit` in the Git repository would become your commit hook, and the next commit you ran would run whatever arbitrary commands an attacker put into that file.  There's a check to avoid this, but it turned out it was slightly broken.)  For implementation-specific reasons this particular security issue shows up as a bad "tree object" that "contains '.git'", which is configured through `hasDotGit`.<sup>1</sup>

Not every version of Git has every test, though, and as new problems have been discovered over the years, new versions of Git have acquired new protections against these old problems.  If *you* have an older version of Git, your Git may be allowing insecure and/or incorrect items—such as this bad `tree` object—to be stored.  Upgrading to a newer version of Git, or accessing a newer version of Git on some server, will sometimes diagnose, or even start refusing to work with, a bad repository.

[As of Git version 2.6, you can configure Git to accept certain bad repository items](https://github.com/blog/2066-git-2-6-including-flexible-fsck-and-improved-status), even if you have checking turned on in general.  (Prior to 2.6 you must simply turn checking off entirely.)  You can choose to ignore some problems, downgrade some issues to warning level, upgrade warnings to errors, and/or ignore some particular objects by their hash IDs.  This configuration must be done *on* the server; whether, and how, it can be done on the servers you are using, I do not know.  See also [this GitLab forum posting](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/462), which suggests that something or someone has been turning this off and on over time.

For reference, Git versions 2.2.1, 2.1.4, 2.0.5, 1.9.5, and 1.8.5 were the points at which Git began checking for `.git` spelled in NTFS and MacOS (HFS) specific ways and with case insensitivity (before that, `.Git` or `.gIt` or `.GIT`, for instance, were all accepted as OK—which they generally are on Linux/Unix systems).  These checks are in `fsck.c` and are optionally invoked on all pack upload, download, and indexing operations.  See the `git config` documentation, searching for every instance of `fsck`, as there are numerous configuration knobs to enable or disable checking entirely, or change the severity of issues.

To reduce the severity of `hasDotGit` to `warning`, you would do:

```
$ git config fsck.hasDotGit warning
```

within that specific repository.

Besides reconfiguring servers, you can also choose to rewrite the history of a bad repository (using `git filter-branch`) to make it into a good repository.  If you do so, though, you will essentially force all your users to re-clone.

---

<sup>1</sup>The exact form of the text message undergoes internationalization, but the default is `contains '.git'` and the configuration string is `hasDotGit`.

The configuration strings are not obvious, and seem not to be properly documented.  They are formed by taking the [enumerated names in the fsck.c source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/fsck.c#L22-L66) and stripping out all underscores and translating to lowercase, then re-upper-casing wherever you like to make camelCase names.  (The `git config` string comparisons are done with case insensitivity, so you can actually configure `fsck.hasdotgit` or `fsck.HASDOTGIT` if you like.  The camelCase is just a convention.)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the problem was. Two years ago a Git repo was added to a directory and checked in to TFS. It was removed again and checked in. It seems that because my Git repository has the history of this it will throw the error due to the reasons outlined by torek.

My solution was to truncate the history to a date after this check-in and it all pushed fine after that.

Thanks for the help